# How to add ColorPicker to a menu (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx

I am creating a program in which you can change the color of shapes, I would like the ColorPicker to be on the top menu along with my other items but I am unsure how to do this.

When I try and add the ColorPicker it says I need to add a menuItem instead, Im unsure if I can convert the picker to a menuItem or if I will have to use a different style of menuBar?

```
public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception{
        BorderPane temp = new BorderPane();
        MenuBar mb = new MenuBar();
        Menu menu = new Menu("test");
        ColorPicker picker = new ColorPicker();
        CustomMenuItem pickerItem = new CustomMenuItem(picker);
        menu.getItems().add(pickerItem);
        mb.getMenus().add(menu);
        temp.setTop(mb);
        Scene newScene = new Scene(temp,400,400);
        primaryStage.setScene(newScene);
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");

        primaryStage.show();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: This lets me add it to the dropdown but I still cant actually use the colorPicker? Like I can see the picker but clicking on it doesnt do anything

Comment: Ive now updated the post with essentially what I have, it lets the picker be on the menu but I cant actually use it so im probably missing something

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Menu.html)

> The `items` `ObservableList` allows for any `MenuItem` type to be inserted, including its subclasses [`Menu`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/Menu.html), [`MenuItem`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/MenuItem.html), [`RadioMenuItem`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/RadioMenuItem.html), [`CheckMenuItem`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/CheckMenuItem.html), [`CustomMenuItem`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html) and [`SeparatorMenuItem`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/SeparatorMenuItem.html). In order to insert an arbitrary `Node` to a `Menu`, a `CustomMenuItem` can be used.

So a `CustomMenuItem` can be used. Note, again referring to the [documentation](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html):

> A useful property of this class is [`hideOnClick`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/20/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/control/CustomMenuItem.html#hideOnClickProperty()). This `boolean` specifies whether the `CustomMenuItem` will be automatically hidden should the user click within the bounds of the `CustomMenuItem`. This is of particular use when the node inside this `CustomMenuItem` is a control that requires user interaction, as by setting the `hideOnClick` property to `false` means the user can interact with it without the menu hiding.

Since a `ColorPicker` is almost certainly a control with which you want the user to interact, you need to set `hideOnClick` to `false`.

Here is a minimal example:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.control.CustomMenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;
import javafx.scene.shape.Rectangle;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class ColorMenuApp extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) {
        MenuBar menuBar = new MenuBar();
        Menu colorMenu = new Menu("Color");
        ColorPicker colorPicker = new ColorPicker(Color.BLACK);
        CustomMenuItem colorMenuItem = new CustomMenuItem(colorPicker);
        colorMenuItem.setHideOnClick(false);
        colorMenu.getItems().add(colorMenuItem);
        menuBar.getMenus().add(colorMenu);

        BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setTop(menuBar);

        Pane pane = new Pane();
        Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(50, 50, 800, 500);
        rectangle.fillProperty().bind(colorPicker.valueProperty());
        pane.getChildren().add(rectangle);
        borderPane.setCenter(pane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(borderPane, 1000, 700);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
}
```